# JS/DOM selector scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Is it possible to have some sort of Id scoping when manipulating DOM with JS?

I use jQuery as my JS framework.

For example:

Is there any mechanism that would allow to select someDiv children of first or someDiv children of second, or do all ids on the page have to be unique?

I know this would be doable using classes (jQuery selector would be .first>.someDiv), but is this doable for the id property as well?

---

Edit: for clarification, here's a more complete example:

File picture_editor.php:

...

JS script for this editor, that needs to manipulate picture_id

...

File main_view.php:

...

Script that manipulates picture_id

...

include(picture_editor.php);

...

Now in the case where picture_editor is included in a file (like main_view) that has an element with the same id as elements in picture_editor, something somewhere is going to stop working (whether it's some script in picture_editor or main_view, or both).
Question: How do you go around that?

Comment: I cannot understand point of asking such question, you can check it in a few minutes by creating some sample page and toying in firebug console with jquery selectors.

Comment: Then what's the way you do it? I know this won't work. But it's still necessary to scope if you include files from other places

Comment: Probably I don't understand your question correctly, please elaborate more and give clear example.

Comment: Please see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

> HTML id attribute, Definition and
>   Usage:
>
> - The id attribute specifies a unique    id for an HTML element.
> - The id must be unique within the HTML    document.
> - The id attribute can be used by a    JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) or by
>     CSS to make changes or style the
>     element with the specified id.

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

All ids need to be unique, so I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

If your `id`s are not unique, then your page is not valid HTML. Rethink your structure if you have non-unique `id`.

As for whether jQuery supports it, it's unlikely, as it should never meet that scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately, many (most?) browsers work "well enough" that having more than one element with the same ID is allowed, *and* selecting an element by ID 'works' (it is not clear if the same element is selected across browsers, though) using document.getElementById.